# The type pointed by pointer at compile time like typeof

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Is there a way to get the type of the data pointed by a pointer? I am interested in something similar with typeof. I wish I can explain it better with a snippet of code:

```
struct_t *pointer1;
struct_t **pointer2;
typeof_ptr(pointer) a;  // here a should be of type struct_t
typeof_ptr(pointer) b;  // here b should also be of type struct_t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `typeof(*pointer1)`, but `typeof(*pointer2)` will be `struct_t*` not `struct_t`; you would need to do `typeof(**pointer2)`.

Keep in mind that `typeof()` is a GCC extension.

Comment: I don't have in advance knowledge of what kind of pointer it will be. I need it for a macro. I know typeof is an extension.

Comment: I honestly can't see a use for this without a corresponding way to actually retrieve the value, but if that's really what you need then the answer is no. This smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)… maybe you should take a step back and think about why you think you need this.

Comment: It's more of an exercise of doing a sort of classes in c, the idea is to store the pointer to the object who is calling the function in a global variable and to do so I'm imagining something like this `#define O(x) (((typeof_ptr(&x) *)class_handle(&x))->vt)` and functions would be called  O(object)->member() or O(object_ptr)->member(). Every class would have a member called vt that actually stores the member functions.